# Calling properties from all vertices on a graph path in gremlin

Tags: database, graph, gremlin

I am building a heterogenous graph database looking at organisational structures. The vertices are: people, role, entity and each have different properties.

I want to be able to return properties from the different vertices but can’t seem to get all three vertices and multiple properties from each of them.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what are you looking for ? relationship schema and the query you used to get the path could be good to start with. 
Also, what is the expected output.

Comment: Hi Prashant. Lets say the vertex and edge flow looks like this:                                 Person (first name, last name, age) —(fills)—> role (role name, role type, rank) <— (has) — entity (entity name, address, entity type) and I want the output to be for one instance (let’s say his name is Bob) and I want to show all his roles and the entities that they come from.

Answer (score 0):

from what I see in your comment

> (first name, last name, age) —(fills)—> role (role name, role type, rank) <— (has) — entity (entity name, address, entity type)

You can try:

```
g.V("person").
  has("first name", "Bob").
  out("fils").as("a").
  in("has").as("b").
  select("a", "b").by(valueMap())
```

Comment: Prashant thanks that’s the right idea! However I need results from person,role and entity. The select function only calls data from person and role . Any thoughts? I could do a valueMap of the whole path, but I want selective data.

Comment: Edit: thanks prashant I understand what you were saying. That works amazingly thanks!